# Vector VRL Unit testing returning undefined fuction for strlen

Tags: logging, yaml, datadog, vector-vrl

https://vector.dev/docs/reference/vrl/functions/#strlen
Hello everyone
I have a transform containing this field and everything is working well and logs are good :

```
    .msg = slice(.message, start: int!(strlen(join!(arrayvar, separator: " "))) , end: int!(strlen(.message))) ?? "undefined"
```

BUT unit testing return `undefined function did you mean "string"?` on strlen function.

Anyone has an idea please?

Comment: This question is missing information, like a valid example of a unit-test showing this error. 

I tried creating a simple transform with this code and the transform itself is not valid. 
Also - you did not specify the version you are using which makes this question unanswerable..

Provide more details to allow answering this question.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of Vector are you running? That function was added in `v0.21.0`.